# How to make a single/double legthed string to minmum of five character legthed in php?

Tags: php, strlen

For my site, I need to do the following

```
$value = "1|22";    
$explode = explode("|",$value);    
$a = $explode[0];    
$b = $explode[1];
```

This will return a and b as 1 and 22 as expected. But I need them to return $a as 00001 and $b as 00022. So if they contain less than 5 characters, I want to add 0 as prefix to it to make it a five-digit number. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = str_pad($explode[0], 5, '0');
$b = str_pad($explode[1], 5, '0');
```

With PHP5.3 you can prepend the `0` like this

```
$explode = array_map (function ($entry) {
    return str_pad($entry, 5, '0');
}, $explode);
```

and assigning

```
list($a, $b) = $explode;
```

At all (still php5.3)

```
list($a, $b) = array_map (function ($entry) {
    return str_pad($entry, 5, '0');
}, explode('|', $value));
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I used a litte modification  $a= str_pad((int) $explode_quote[0],5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
$value = "1|22";    
$explode = explode("|",$value);    
$a = sprintf( '%1$05d', $explode[0] );    
$b = sprintf( '%1$05d', $explode[1] );
```